# Prestashop product stock and product combinations doesn't match

Tags: combinations, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

On ours Prestashop shop we have some issue. After adding product with combination and after it sold out combinations still have 10 items in stock when main product stock on product list have 0 product in stock. How can i refresh that informations.

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: You need to again save the product from the admin and it will refresh the main stock of product.

Comment: Hello. Thank yoou for resposne but it didn't help. Still one product on prodict list have 8 in stock but in variations (only one, default) is 4 in stock